Quadratic where roots and coefficients together form Arithmetic Progression
Background
I was reading this post: A.P. terms in a Quadratic equation.
And wondered the following: Given a quadratic $ax^2+bx+c=0$ which has roots $x=m,x=n$, is it possible for $a,m,b,n,c$ to be consecutive terms in an Arithmetic Progression?
There are plenty of posts about polynomials where the coefficients form an AP, but I couldn't find anything about the coefficients and the roots (alternating since there will be one less root than coefficient) forming an AP themselves.
What I have found so far
It may seem trivial to some but I first decided to test whether or not $m=n$ was a possibility.
This led to quadratics of the form $ax^2+ax+a=0$ which does not have real roots, so $m=n=a$ does not work. I believe this means it is safe to conclude $m \neq n$.
Because $a,m,b,n,c$ are in AP, $b-a=n-m$ and by Vieta's formula (one of them anyway) $m+n=\frac{-b}{a}$
This gives the result $m=\frac{a^2-ab-b}{2a}$. But since $m$ is the arithmetic mean of $a,b$ it follows also that $m=\frac{a+b}{2}$.
This means $\frac{a^2-ab-b}{2a}=\frac{a+b}{2}$ and so either $b=0$ or $a=\frac{-1}{2}$.
If $b=0$ I can find two quadratics: $2x^2-2$ (the sequence is $2,1,0,-1,-2$) and $-2x^2+2$ (same sequence, opposite order).
If $a=\frac{-1}{2}$ I can find two quadratics also:
$\frac{-1}{2}x^2+\frac{-5+2\sqrt{5}}{2}x+\frac{-9+4\sqrt{5}}{2}$ and $\frac{-1}{2}x^2+\frac{-5-2\sqrt{5}}{2}x+\frac{-9-4\sqrt{5}}{2}$
The first quadratic has roots $m=\frac{-6+2\sqrt{5}}{2},n=\frac{-7+3\sqrt{5}}{2}$ and the second has roots $m=\frac{-3-\sqrt{5}}{2},n=\frac{-7-3\sqrt{5}}{2}$.
Where to now?
Firstly, I am curious to know if I have made any incorrect assumptions in this approach and secondly, is it possible for some of $a,m,b,n,c$ to be complex numbers? Instinctively my answer to the second is no but I cannot see a simple reason why or why not.

Your equations are correct, and there are no more if we try to extend to the complex domain.
Given the case $b=0$, we must have
$a=-2d,m=-d,b=0,n=d,c=2d;$
and then the second Vieta formula $mn=c/a$ leads to $d^2=1\implies d=\pm1$. So all the coefficients are fixed to one if the two possibilities for this case. Similarly for $a=-1/2$ we define
$a=-\frac12,m=-\frac12+d,b=-\frac12+2d,n=-\frac12+3d,c=-\frac12+4d;$
and $mn=c/a\implies4d^2+8d-1=0$. Again there are only the two real roots you identified already for this case, no more.
